Azure Data Factory (ADF) Is it possible to compare the schema of a .csv file against the schema of a database before writing to it
I have a requirement to get the schema of a database and compare it against a provided .csv (coming from azure blob storage) which headers should match exactly the database schema before start writing the data of the csv to the db.
I was planining to use 2 get metadata activities to get the abovementioned schemas and then compare it againt each other.
I wanted to use the forEach activity but Im kind stuck with it.
The schema of the database will change "often" (also quite extensive) so a hardcoded solution would not be ideal
Any recommendation on how I could use a pipeline or a dataflow for this?

do you want to compare only the headers right? cauz the CSV file will give data types as strings from Get meta data activity sometimes even for the integers or date times.

Thats what happened in my case also. I tried to comapre the datatypes but all of them were strings. For now comparing the headers with columns names is enough. Later on when I ll try to write to the db I hope that it will complain if the format is not the right one

on maximum how many columns will be there in your table?

Its gonna be a lot. More than 150, but the number is dynamic. Columns are added and removed all the time. Thats why Im looking for a dynamic solution

To achieve your requirement, after both Get meta data activities, you can use Filter activity and contains() functions inside it.
First, add column count Field list in both Get meta data activities.


Then add Filter activity and use below dynamic expressions in it.
Items: - @activity('Get table structure').output.structure

Condition - @contains(activity('Get csv structure').output.structure,json(concat('{"name":"',item().name,'","type":"String"}')))


Filter activity is used to filter out items from a given a list based on given condition.
Both structure arrays are not identical JSON arrays to compare. That's why give the Table structure JSON array as items and use contains() in the condition. contains() function will give true/false if a given item is in the given list or not. Give the CSV structure array to this function and build a JSON as per this JSON item structure using the current name item().name from the Table structure array.
By this way, it will check whether all the column names from table structure exists or not in the CSV structure and it satisfies, it will give the same count as below.

Later, use If activity. In this expression, check whether columns count from both Get meta data activities are same or not and the counts from Filter activity are same or not.
@and(equals(activity('Get csv structure').output.columnCount,activity('Get table structure').output.columnCount),equals(activity('Filter1').output.ItemsCount,activity('Filter1').output.FilteredItemsCount))


Inside True activities of If, you can go ahead with your activities.
As nested if activities are not supported in ADF, you need to do this column headers check before the if activity and check it in the if activity expression. You can check multiple expressions in the same expression using nested and() dynamic expression.
@and(and(<expression>,<expression>)>,and(<expression>,<expression>))


Amazing, gimme some time to test it out and Ill accept

Did it worked for you?

IM going to test it out later today and I ll let you know!!

Is there a way to extract the items(together with their source, if theya re coming from the db or the csv) that they dont match?

If the if condition is not true, you can have a filter activity in false activities of if. In that check the condition by not(<contains() function>). The first filter activity will give the matched columns list and this filter in the false activities is reverse to it which will give not matching columns list.

Indeed a simple not did the trick. It seems that it works perfectly fine. A big thanks again!!!

One more side question: Is there a way to get rid of the redundant info that comes from the tables data metadata and only keep an array with the columns names that don't match the csv headers?

Get meta data activity for the tables by default adds those meta data. You cannot get rid of that without hardcoding the keys of that JSON. If it is more important, then you can use Lookup activity with query like SELECT COLUMN_NAME as name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'yourTableName' to get the column names instead of Get meta data activity. But you need to change the Filter activity and if activity expressions to compare this lookup output array and csv structure array. You need to change this as per the lookup output.

More than clear enough. I might use the look up option as I have a requirement to exclude some of the incoming columns and I m not sure how to do that via the filter/if activities

First try from your end and if you got blockers, you could raise a new ask on this issue with required details so that I can try from my end.
